# How to parse a JSON string in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, json, delphi-xe

How can I parse the JSON string

```json
{"data":{"results":[{"Branch":"ACCT590003"}]}}
```

using the [`TJSONObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBXJSON.TJSONObject) object? I want to get the `ACCT590003` value from this string.

Answer (score 40):

You don't need to use external libraries to perform a JSONPath search.
Example with Delphi 10 Seattle:

```
uses  System.JSON;
procedure ParseJSonValue;
var
   JSonValue:TJSonValue;
   st:string;
   Branch: string;
begin
   st := '{"data":{"results":[{"Branch":"ACCT590003"}]}}';
   JsonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(st);
   Branch := JsonValue.GetValue<string>('data.results[0].Branch');
   JsonValue.Free;
end;
```

Comment: The original question was about creating an instance of `TJSonObject` and not about receiving a `TJsonValue`.. ^^

Comment: This solution is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: This is much easier than my attempt to use TJsonIterator

Comment: To convert to JSONObjet , do CAST:  MyJSONObject := (JsonValue as TJSONObject);

Comment: The solution is working. I just wanted to add that ('data.results[0].Branch') is case sensitive

Answer (score 21):

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  DBXJSON;

type
  TProcessJSONString = TProc<TJSONString>;

procedure DoJSONObject(o: TJSONObject; Process: TProcessJSONString); forward;

procedure DoJSONArray(o: TJSONArray; Process: TProcessJSONString);
var i: integer;
    v: TJSONValue;
begin
  for i := 0 to o.Size - 1 do begin
    v := o.Get(i);
    if v is TJSONObject then
      DoJSONObject(v as TJSONObject, Process);
  end;
end;

procedure DoJSONObject(o: TJSONObject; Process: TProcessJSONString);
var i: integer;
    p: TJSONPair;
begin
  for i := 0 to o.Size - 1 do begin
    p := o.Get(i);
    Process(p.JsonString);
    if p.JsonValue is TJSONObject then
      DoJSONObject(p.JsonValue as TJSONObject, Process)
    else if p.JsonValue is TJSONArray then
      DoJSONArray(p.JsonValue as TJSONArray, Process)
    else if p.JsonValue is TJSONString then
      Process(p.JsonValue as TJSONString);
  end;
end;

var o: TJSONObject;
begin
  o := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"data":{"results":[{"Branch":"ACCT590003"}]}}') as TJSONObject;
  try
    DoJSONObject(o,
      procedure (o: TJSONString)
      begin
        WriteLn(o.ToString);
      end
    );
  finally
    o.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: While good, it's generally preferred to use the system available libraries to keep maintaining the code easier.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Saved my day!

Answer (score 10):

Try this code, it works fine

```
uses System.JSON;

procedure _Parse_JSonValue;
var
   JSonObject:TJSonObject;
   JSonValue:TJSonValue;
   st:string;
   Branch: string;
Begin
   st := '{"data":{"results":[{"Branch":"ACCT590003"}]}}';
   JSonObject := TJSonObject.Create;
   JsonValue:=JSonObject.ParseJSONValue(st);
   JsonValue:=(JsonValue as TJSONObject).Get('data').JSONValue;
   JsonValue:=(JsonValue as TJSONObject).Get('results').JSONValue;
   if (JSONValue is TJSONArray) then
      Branch := ((JSONValue as TJSONArray).Items[0] as TJSonObject).Get('Branch').JSONValue.Value;
   JSonObject.Free;
End;
```

Branch = 'ACCT590003'

Answer (score 6):

Using SuperObject Library https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject/

```
var json: iSuperObject;
    data: string;

begin
  json := SO('{"data":{"results":[{"Branch":"ACCT590003"}]}}'); // shorthand
// or equal:  JSON := TSuperObject.ParseString('{"data":{"results":[{"Branch":"ACCT590003"}]}}');

  data := json.S['data.results[0].Branch'];

  WriteLn('Result is: ', data);
end.
```

Answer (score 5):

using [TALdocument](https://sourceforge.net/p/alcinoe/wiki/ALJsonDocument/) it's easy

```
AJsonDoc := TalJsonDocument.create;
AjsonDoc.loadFromJsonString('{"data":{"results":[{"Branch":"ACCT590003"}]}}');
writeln(AjsonDoc.childnode['data']['result'][0]['Branch'].text);
```