# How to parse json files using ISuperObject in Delphi 10

Tags: json, delphi

I'm trying to parse a JSON file using ISuperObject.  My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "follows":{
      "count":868,
      "page_info":{
         "has_previous_page":false,
         "start_cursor":null,
         "end_cursor":"SbXc6VJsoeTs",
         "has_next_page":true
      },
      "nodes":[
         {
            "username":"username1",
            "requested_by_viewer":false,
            "followed_by_viewer":true,
            "profile_pic_url":"URL link",
            "full_name":"name",
            "is_verified":false,
            "id":"ID"
         },
         {
            "username":"username2",
            "requested_by_viewer":false,
            "followed_by_viewer":true,
            "profile_pic_url":"URL link",
            "full_name":"username2",
            "is_verified":false,
            "id":"ID"
         },
         {
            "username":"_username3",
            "..."
         ]
      }
```

I want all of the `username` values to be listed in a Memo.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var
 json         : ISuperObject;
 row_item     : ISuperObject;
begin
  json := TSuperObject.ParseFile('C:\json.txt', TRUE); 
  for row_item in json['nodes'] do 
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(elements_itemS['usernames']); 
  end;
end;
```

I get an Access Violation on the `for` loop.  Any ideas?

Comment: `for username in json['nodes'] do through elements array` is not valid Delphi code, which means it's not what you have tried. If you want help with your code, **post your code**. It seems to me we've had this discussion before...

Comment: i used this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415616/how-to-parse-specified-value-from-json-object-in-delphi-xe3], maybe. @KenWhite

Comment: The code you linked does not use ISuperObject, and it's not anything like the code you've posted here. I repeat: If you want help with your code, **post YOUR CODE**. Not something else, not a link to something unrelated, not something you made up while writing your question here - the **actual code** that you **copy and paste** from the IDE's code editor, that will actually compile.

Comment: i used the second answer from that post, with some changes,however, the code compiles successfully. updated. @KenWhite

Comment: @KenWhite: `for row_item in json['nodes']` is valid Delphi code. It is a [container iteration loop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements) using an Enumerator, and `ISuperObject` implements a Delphi-compatible Enumerator for JSON nodes. However, the `elements_itemS` looks suspicious wrong.

Comment: @Remy: Can you point me to the documentation where it says *for <var> in <list> do through elements array** is acceptable to the compiler? It's not valid code - valid code *compiles*. I'm fully aware of the correct syntax to use for `for..in`, and that isn't it. The poster should include **valid code**.

Comment: @KenWhite: `for..in` is documented on the link I posted in my last comment. Or, are you referring to the `through elements array*` portion?

Comment: @Remy: That link does not say what you indicate it does. There's no `do through elements array` anywhere in that syntax or the examples. I'm referring to the poster including something indicated as what has **been tried** when clearly that's not it, because what was posted will not compile, and then the link received in reply was to something totally not related to ISuperObject (it uses TJSONObject instead, and doesn't even look vaguely like what's posted here.)

Comment: @KenWhite: there is no `elements_itemS` in `ISuperObject`, so where are you getting `elements array*` from?

Comment: @Remy: From the post before it was just edited. Look at the initial post (revision 1), which is when I asked for the actual code.

Comment: Pretty disappointing that you post invalid JSON and code that does not compile. Your real problem is a lack of attention to detail. You need to learn the discipline of how to prepare a [mcve].

Comment: well, this is first time dealing with JSON, however, updated @DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code should look more like this instead:

```pascal
var
  json         : ISuperObject;
  node         : ISuperObject;
  item         : IMember;
begin
  json := TSuperObject.ParseFile('C:\json.txt', TRUE); 
  for item in json.O['follows'].A['nodes'] do 
  begin
    node := item.AsObject;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(node.S['username']); 
  end;
end;
```

Or this:

```pascal
var
  json         : ISuperObject;
  node         : ISuperObject;
  item         : IMember;
begin
  json := TSuperObject.ParseFile('C:\json.txt', TRUE); 
  for item in json['follows.nodes'].AsArray do 
  begin
    node := item.AsObject;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(node.S['username']); 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `json['nodes'].AsArray` causes this error `for-in statement cannot operate on collection type 'TSuperArray' because 'TSuperArray' does not contain a member for 'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible`. removing `AsArray` causes Access Violation!

Comment: Are you using the [latest version of ISuperObject](https://github.com/delphiframeworks/x-superobject/)? `json['nodes']` returns an `ISuperExpression`, whose `AsArray` property returns an `ISuperArray`, not a `TSuperArray` (`json.A['nodes']` also returns an `ISuperArray`).  `ISuperArray` has a `GetEnumerator()` method for use with Delphi `for..in` loops.

Comment: ok, updated the `ISuperObject` now i get `Incompatible types: 'ISuperObject' and 'ICast'` on both ways in your answer

Comment: The elements of the enumerator are returned as `ICast`, so change your `row_item` variable to `ICast` (or `IMember`, which is an alias for `ICast`), and then you can use `row_item.AsObject['username'].AsString` or `row_item.AsObject.S['username']`.

Comment: alright, it compiles now, but nothing is added to Memo1!, i opened the debugger and there is no processes added after i click Button1 in the event log

Comment: @ColdZer0 why would you expect a new process to be started? There is no process involved. Now, let's start with the obvious- what does your **real** JSON look like? Because what is in your question is invalid JSON. The code in my answer is based on an *assumption* of what the real JSON looks like. Can you confirm it?

Comment: updated the JSON, is there a difference ? @Remy Lebeau

Comment: my bad very sorry, this my first time dealing with JSON i thought  it wont make a change if i deleted some parts, lesson learned, Thanks for the information and your efforts @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @Remy - thanks for your comment. I have deleted my post. Regards.

Comment: @ColdZer0: yes, there is a difference, because now the `username` values are located at a different level in the hierarchy, which requires slightly different code to reach. I have updated my answer to compensate for that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how to  `end_cursor` value, i tried `Memo1.Lines.Add(json['followed_by.count..page_info.end_cursor'].AsString);` but i get nothing

Comment: @ColdZer0: There is no `followed_by` object in the JSON you showed. The `end_cursor` is a value of the `page_info` object inside the `follows` object: `Memo1.Lines.Add(json['follows.page_info.end_cursor'].AsString);`